# How to Disable Logging by Android O/S - Seek API

Tags: android, api, logging, seek

I would like to know how to disable the logging that happens as a result of the Android O/S API and not my payment app itself.

http://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/

I have no control over it as its dependent on the O/S itself and it writes to logcat file.

Any advise highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know how to disable the logging that happens as a result of the Android O/S API and not my payment app itself.

That would require modifications to the firmware itself. Other applications, including those that are part of the firmware, are welcome to log whatever they want to LogCat. Your "payment app" has no rights to affect what information other applications log. Hence, the only way to "disable the logging" would be to disable LogCat entirely, and no SDK application can do that.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. This is my current status as I am stuck with waiting for firmware update or to encrypt the info that is being logged.